# Golang - Zip a directory which includes empty subdirectory and files

Tags: go, zip

I am trying to zip an existing directory that has some empty subdirectories as well.

Here is the folder structure.

```
parent/
├── child
│   └── child.txt
├── empty-folder
└── parent.txt

2 directories, 2 files
```

Here is the source code. It writes all the subdirectories which have files on that. But it skipped an empty subdirectory. Is there any way to add an empty subdirectory as well in the zip file?. Thanks in advance.

```
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

// check for error and stop the execution
func checkForError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error - ", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

const (
    ZIP_FILE_NAME    = "example.zip"
    MAIN_FOLDER_NAME = "parent"
)

// Main function
func main() {

    var targetFilePaths []string

    // get filepaths in all folders
    err := filepath.Walk(MAIN_FOLDER_NAME, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }
        // add all the file paths to slice
        targetFilePaths = append(targetFilePaths, path)
        return nil
    })
    checkForError(err)

    // zip file logic starts here
    ZipFile, err := os.Create(ZIP_FILE_NAME)
    checkForError(err)
    defer ZipFile.Close()

    zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(ZipFile)
    defer zipWriter.Close()

    for _, targetFilePath := range targetFilePaths {

        file, err := os.Open(targetFilePath)
        checkForError(err)
        defer file.Close()

        // create path in zip
        w, err := zipWriter.Create(targetFilePath)
        checkForError(err)

        // write file to zip
        _, err = io.Copy(w, file)
        checkForError(err)

    }

}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do empty directories need to be included for your use case?

Comment: Search for the word "directory" in the zip package documentation, it explains https://pkg.go.dev/archive/zip

Comment: Maybe this help you: https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/Te0oScOV3KM

Comment: @kingkupps just want to maintain the correct folder structure. The target machine needs to process and it may throw an error if there is no folder on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write an empty directory you just need to call [`Create`](https://pkg.go.dev/archive/zip#Writer.Create) with the directory path with a trailing path separator.

```
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

const (
    ZIP_FILE_NAME    = "example.zip"
    MAIN_FOLDER_NAME = "parent"
)

type fileMeta struct {
    Path  string
    IsDir bool
}

func main() {
    var files []fileMeta
    err := filepath.Walk(MAIN_FOLDER_NAME, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        files = append(files, fileMeta{Path: path, IsDir: info.IsDir()})
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    z, err := os.Create(ZIP_FILE_NAME)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer z.Close()

    zw := zip.NewWriter(z)
    defer zw.Close()

    for _, f := range files {
        path := f.Path
        if f.IsDir {
            path = fmt.Sprintf("%s%c", path, os.PathSeparator)
        }

        w, err := zw.Create(path)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }

        if !f.IsDir {
            file, err := os.Open(f.Path)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln(err)
            }
            defer file.Close()

            if _, err = io.Copy(w, file); err != nil {
                log.Fatalln(err)
            }
        }
    }
}
```